# Does a C pointer refer to the physical or virtual address

Tags: c, pointers

When I am using a pointer in C for a PC program, does it point to the physical or virtual address of the variable ?

```
int x = 10;
int* ptr = &x;
```

Comment: Generally in most OS cases (Windows, Linux, MAC) to virtual memory and then MMU map it to real physical address.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It depends.

If you're writing a application that will run on top of a operating system, that is, in user mode and the operating system uses virtual memory, it will point to a virtual address (or rather, it will point to a physical address but not the same physical address that will in fact be used).

If you're using an operating system without virtual memory or if you're writing (parts) of the kernel code it will point to the physical address.

Answer (score 10):

It depends on your OS!

In Windows and Linux it's typical virtual memory! Also user space application canno't access the memory using physical addresses.

Answer (score 5):

If there *is* an underlying OS (not taking embedded systems into account), and it is not a special kind of low-level application (drivers, stacks), the address will always be virtual.